# Daterange with startDate and endDate not working if both date same

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I get the data returned of the selected date range which is between the range or isnt. but not if the startDate and endDate is the same. Like example: from 14.10.2017 - 14.10.2017. It returns me then no data (but it should because 5 database records are affected)

```
foreach (Content content in db.Contents)
{
   if (content.ShippedDate < startDate || content.ShippedDate > endDate)
}
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Is the end of the date range *meant* to be inclusive or exclusive? That's the first thing to decide.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the condition to include the same date.

```
1.1.2016 < 1.1.2016   //FALSE
1.1.2016 <= 1.1.2016  //TRUE
```

Adjusting conditions:

```
content.ShippedDate <= startDate 
content.ShippedDate >= endDate
```

Code:

```
foreach (Content content in db.Contents)
{
    if (content.ShippedDate <= startDate || content.ShippedDate >= endDate)
        //the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<=` (smaller than or equal) and `>=` (greater than or equal) instead of `<` and `>`, this will match values that are equal as well rather than just the ones that are smaller or greater than given value.

Also please refer to this page to learn more about c# operators as this is a very basic questions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx